# ADF session log for dynamic schema based copy activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have followed microsoft documentation for session log. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-log
here is snippet of my copy activity

"logSettings": {
"enableCopyActivityLog": true,
"copyActivityLogSettings": {
"logLevel": "Info",
"enableReliableLogging": false
},
"logLocationSettings": {
"linkedServiceName": {
"referenceName": "ls_adlsgen2_landingzone",
"type": "LinkedServiceReference"
},
"path": "sessionlogs"
}

as part of the output of the copy activity I am expecting log file to have data read, writes, row read, written, copy duration, throughput etc, however all I see is start and end of file writes. am I missing anything? looks like session log does not logs insights of copied file..is there any way to get those details out?

output session log file
Timestamp,Level,OperationName,OperationItem,Message
2021-11-18 21:30:36.3698967,Info,FileWrite,"202111181630.parquet","Start to write file."
2021-11-18 21:30:37.5773470,Info,FileWrite,"202111181630.parquet","Complete writing file. File is successfully copied."

Comment: If the answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution.

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-log#the-schema-of-the-log-file),  schema of a log file is as shown below

[image]

Unfortunately, you can get only **Timestamp, Level, OperationName, OperationItem, Message**
columns in log file.

Sample log file

```
Timestamp, Level, OperationName, OperationItem, Message
2020-10-19 08:39:13.6688152,Info,FileRead,"sample1.csv","Start to read file: {""Path"":""sample1.csv"",""ItemType"":""File"",""Size"":104857620,""LastModified"":""2020-10-19T08:22:31Z"",""ETag"":""\""0x8D874081F80C01A\"""",""ContentMD5"":""dGKVP8BVIy6AoTtKnt+aYQ=="",""ObjectName"":null}"
2020-10-19 08:39:56.3190846, Warning, FileSkip, "sample1.csv", "File is skipped after read 548000000 bytes: ErrorCode=DataConsistencySourceDataChanged,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Source file 'sample1.csv' is changed by other clients during the copy activity run.,Source=,'." 
2020-10-19 08:40:13.6688152,Info,FileRead,"sample2.csv","Start to read file: {""Path"":""sample2.csv"",""ItemType"":""File"",""Size"":104857620,""LastModified"":""2020-10-19T08:22:31Z"",""ETag"":""\""0x8D874081F80C01A\"""",""ContentMD5"":""dGKVP8BVIy6AoTtKnt+aYQ=="",""ObjectName"":null}"
2020-10-19 08:40:13.9003981,Info,FileWrite,"sample2.csv","Start to write file from source file: sample2.csv."
2020-10-19 08:45:17.6508407,Info,FileRead,"sample2.csv","Complete reading file successfully. "
2020-10-19 08:45:28.7390083,Info,FileWrite,"sample2.csv","Complete writing file from source file: sample2.csv. File is successfully copied."
```

---

**Update -**

Unfortunately, I could not find anything to get insights about the data transfer metrics

You can request this feature [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/79b1327d-d925-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f06a4)

Comment: thank you Abhishek. That's what I am seeing in the output session-log blob store.  Any idea if they have any undocumented settings to get insights about the data transfer metrics? Looks like its available for visual inspection and should be part of customer managed subscription but not yet made available to end user to consume.

Comment: @ShrikantKulkarni, I have updated answer. Please Check.